# image data encoded problem

Tags: php, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i want to store image in MYsql Database using Php.getting Nsdata from uiimage,encoded this Nsdata to string.This string contains huge no of characters.when i m passing this string to PHP, url becomes nil.My PHP decoding img and ruuning perfectly.Only i m getting problem in sending string to PHP. plz guide me...

Thanks.

Comment: Do you pass this data as POST parameter or via GET?

Comment: Via GET.when i run php manually image is inserting into mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some months ago I was working on something similar, here's the code which I used to upload a picture and some other related fileds. The data is received by a php script that stores the picture as BLOB type.

```
- (void)allSet {
// Creating the url request:
NSURL *cgiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a-server.com/upload.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:cgiUrl];
// Your request should be POST
NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0194784892923"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
[postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
// Here's were your get the picture's data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.thePicture.photo, 0.5);

//setting up the body:
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"category\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"photos"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"format\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"JSON"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:thePicture.title] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:thePicture.description] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"latitude\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [thePicture.latitude floatValue]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"longitude\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [thePicture.longitude floatValue]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", thePicture.title] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//adding header information:
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
[theConnection start];

if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData that will hold
    // the received data
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // inform the user that the download could not be made
}
```

}

Of course this code will need to be adapted to your needs, I don't have examples for the server side but as I said you should look on how to store BLOB data types. Hope this helps.